# How to enable Visual Studio Code to highlight a Closing tag on clicking a Opening tag?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

After a update visual studio is highlighting all the tags. I want to highlight only the closing tag of the currently selected opening tag.

Comment: VSCode is not VS. Don't misuse tags.

Comment: Do you have "editor.occurrencesHighlight": true in your settings?  If not, that may help.  Let me know.

Comment: Yeah @Mark I have it as true